# What is `store` and `store_bump`

Tags: anchor, web3.js, metaplex, anchor-program-idl

this is like a parent of the program ID , with a new thing which I am not aware of called store, and store_bump, can someone tell me what is this, the child program is

EDMintACJmusW8m6qV2pqd8UWrcyMkFS6AurtX3Bz549
[image]

[image]